# Unresponsive sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using two slider inputs for my R shiny app that displays dates. I can't figure out why, but the slider sometimes gets stuck and I'm unable to drag it.

Here's a snippet of the R code for the slider input. I played around with the margin widths and that didn't make a difference. Any thoughts?

```
       absolutePanel(
         tags$style(type="text/css",
                    ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                    ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
         ),
         id = "hist_panel", class = "panel panel-default",
         fixed = TRUE, draggable = FALSE,
         top = 40, left = "auto", right = 0,
         bottom = "auto",
         width = "35%", height = "auto", #430
         h4("Use the sliders to define migration dates"),
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("NSD",
                    
                    dygraphOutput("plotlraj",height=320, width='95%') ,
                    helpText("Double click the graph or click Reset Zoom to return to full extent.")),
           tabPanel("Elevation",
                    dygraphOutput("plotelev",height=320, width='95%')),
           tabPanel("Animal Info",
                      uiOutput(outputId = "info_animals")
           )
           
         ),
         br(),
         div(style = "margin: auto; width: 90%",
             sliderTextInput("fallrange",
                             "Fall Migration Date Range:",
                             choices = as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="MST"), selected = range(as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="MST")), width = "100%")
             
         ),
         uiOutput(outputId = "fall2"),
         div(style = "margin: auto; width: 100%",
             sliderTextInput("springrange",
                             "Spring Migration Date Range:",
                             choices = as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="MST"),selected = range(as.POSIXct("2021-07-01 01:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="MST")), width = "100%")),
         uiOutput(outputId = "spring2")
         
         
       )
```

Comment: Every time you move the slider the server code is re-running. An action button would fix this issue - https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html

Comment: On a side note: Instead of youtube videos GIFs can be directly embedded in your question. Check [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Comment: So after you drag the slider input you have to click an action button every time you want the graph to update? @MarkDruffel

Comment: @JNN Yes that's right. I'd recommend reading this chapter of Mastering Shiny if you're new to reactive coding - https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html, it really helped me get up to speed with shiny.

Comment: Thanks @MarkDruffel. I tried using an action button which at least helped with the graph rendering. However, my slider inputs are still getting "stuck" on the left side.

Comment: Yea it's been awhile, but I know I've had issues using the sliderInput with dates in the past. Doesn't at all address your point, but you could try using a library for your inputs like shinyWidgets::airDatepicker() to see if it works any better for you - https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/airDatepicker.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware of the fact, that R (by default) is single threaded. Accordingly, long running processes on the server side may block the UI.

In your case every change of the `sliderInput` triggers re-rendering the plot. If the user chages the slider position faster than the server provides the response, the tasks will pile up and the UI is blocked / gets laggy.

To avoid this behaviour you could use a `eventReactive` triggered by an `actionButton` as implied by @MarkDruffel in the comments or you use `debounce()` to slow down the slider.

Here is a *reproducible* example using `debounce`:

```
library(shiny)

DF <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("myslider", "my Slider", min = 1, max = 100, value = c(25, 50)),
  plotOutput("myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  debouncedSlider <- debounce(reactive({input$myslider}), 500)
  
  filteredDF <- reactive({
    DF[debouncedSlider()[1]:debouncedSlider()[2],]
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x = filteredDF()$x, y = filteredDF()$y, type = "l")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: also check `?bindEvent()` and `?bindCache()` in this context.